# How to understand logit results?

Tags: probability

I have some output from a binary logit regression and I have some troubles to interpret it properly. Particularly I would like to know whether the coefficient of “male” tells me about the probability of outcomes 0 and 1 and what role the intecept plays in that example

"Estimate"                      "Std. err."                          "z-score"

(Intercept) $-5.183$           $1.094$                       $-4.738$

Male $0.652$                   $0.318$                          $2.053$

Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps better to post this over at [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Regression of what on what?

Comment: Of several explanatory variables which inlcudes gender on political preference...

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, in a logistic regression one has $$\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)=\beta_0+\langle \beta,x\rangle$$

where $p$ it the probability of the binary outcome r.v. $Y$, while the $x's$ are the independent variables and $\beta$'s the coefficients (to be found by MLE). The coeffcient $\beta_0$ is the intercept. Equivalently one can write
$$p=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta_0-\langle \beta,x\rangle}}$$

and

$$ \mathcal O(x_1,\dots,x_n;\beta):=\frac{p}{1-p}=e^{\beta_0+\langle \beta,x\rangle},$$
where the quantities $\mathcal O(x_1,\dots,x_n;\beta)$ are called odd-ratios.

In logistic regressions the odd ratios are for the interpretation of results.
Let us suppose that the MLE converges and one finds a set of ML estimates $\hat{\beta}$ of $\beta$'s for the given logistic regression model. Then

$$\frac{\mathcal O(x_1,\dots,x_i+1,\dots,x_n;\hat{\beta})}{ \mathcal O(x_1,\dots,x_n;\hat{\beta})}=e^{\hat{\beta}_i},$$

i.e. the exponential of the $i$-th estimated coefficient is equal to the relative increase of odd ratios, increasing the $i$-th regression of one unit and keeping all other regressors constant. Once the interpretation of odd ratios is clear in the given context (where the logistic regression is performed), the above formula gives a strightforward interpretation of results.

Comment: may i ask you to be more practical in respect to my example

Comment: the problem is that in your question it is not clear which kind of regression are you doing (i.e. response variable, covariates etc...), as just the output of a regression is present. I suggest to have a look at my answer for the "theory" and the notes http://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/as2011/asr/ASR-HS10-Scriptum.pdf . Please go to pag.82 for an example with R and pag. 83 for the subsequent use of odd ratios.